# extract date "2017-01-26"(in yyyy-mm-dd) from files name like "abcd.log.2017_01_26_23_30.0"

Tags: shell, command-line, files

I have some files under `/mainFolder/test`:

```
abcd.log.2017_01_26_23_30.0
abcd.log.2017_01_26_23_35.0
abcd.log.2017_02_20_23_10.0
xyz1.log.2017-02-01
xyz2.log.2017-03-11
```

From these files, I need a file like `abcd.log.2017_01_26_23_30.0`. To search, I am trying like:

```
myRegex="[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{1}"
realPath="/mainFolder/test/abcd.log.2017_01_26_23_30.0"
[[ $realPath =~ $myRegex ]] && echo "It is matching" || echo "Does not match"
```

After getting the files, I need to extract the dates in format `yyyy-mm-dd` (that is I need `2017-01-26`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using capture groups and `$BASH_REMATCH` to extract bits of strings:

```
for name in *.log.*; do
    if [[ "$name" =~ \.([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2}) ]]; then
        printf '%d-%d-%d from "%s"\n' \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" \
            "$name"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
2017-01-26 from "abcd.log.2017_01_26_23_30.0"
2017-01-26 from "abcd.log.2017_01_26_23_35.0"
2017-02-20 from "abcd.log.2017_02_20_23_10.0"
```

If you need the date string in a variable:

```
for name in *.log.*; do
    if [[ "$name" =~ \.([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2}) ]]; then
        datestring="$( printf '%d-%d-%d' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" )"
        printf '%s from "%s"\n' "$datestring" "$name"
    fi
done
```

In `ksh93`, replace `BASH_REMATCH` with `.sh.match`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `perl` and tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
  my ( @date ) = m/(\d{4})\D(\d{2})\D(\d{2})/;
  my $date_str = join "-", @date;
  print $date_str,"\n";
}
```

It matches '4 digits', '2 digits',  '2 digits' and reformats them to be `-` delimited. It assumes your numbers are ordered the 'right' way though.